# How to returning value if another value is nil

Tags: ruby

```
a = [3, 2, 7]
a[1] + a[2] # Result : 9
a[1] + a[7]
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
    from (irb):18:in `+'
    from (irb):18
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

how to return a[1] value if a[7] nil?

Comment: Maybe use `if` statement?

Comment: @MarekLipka same result. nil cant be coerced into Fixnum

Comment: Is `a[1] + a[2]` the actual operation you're performing or a simplified example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that `nil.to_i == 0`:

```
a = [3, 2, 7]

a[1].to_i + a[2].to_i
#=> 5

a[1].to_i + a[7].to_i
#=> 2
```

Of course this will only work for addition/subtraction and other operations where the neutral element is `0`. For a more general solution, you can use `||` to set a default value:

```
a = [3, 2, 7]

(a[1] || 1) * (a[2] || 1)
#=> 6

(a[1] || 1) * (a[7] || 1)
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways can be a use of [`fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-fetch) with default value:

```
a = [3, 2, 7]
a.fetch(1, 0) + a.fetch(2, 0) # => 9
a.fetch(1, 0) + a.fetch(7, 0) # => 2
```

Comment: This is better because generally speaking it will also handle the case where `false` is a valid value in the array, `||` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Someone's got to mention the obvious:

```
a[1] + (7 < a.size ? a[7] : 0)
```

Note that if `7 < a.size` and `a[7]` is `nil`, an exception would be raised (good!). By contrast, if we erroneously took `a[7]` being `nil` to mean that `a.size <= 7`, the presence of the errant `nil` would go unreported. Granted, it's pretty rare for `nil`s to appear where they don't belong. Right?